# Is This is issue about varnish "Using this mail function,mail is going but mail template is not showing in mail"

Tags: php, email, magento, varnish, magento-1.8

I added this for sending mail,mail is going but template is not showing in mail. 
seller_mail_template is shwoing in mail but seller_registration_template is not .

```
    $loadTemplateVariables='seller_mail_template';
    $this->commonmail($email,$bccEmail='false',$loadTemplateVariables,$templateSubject,$emailTemplateVariables);
    $loadTemplateVariables ='seller_registration_template';
    $this->commonmail($email,$bccEmail='false',$loadTemplateVariables,$templateSubject,$emailTemplateVariables);
      function commonmail($email,$bccEmail='false',$loadTemplateVariables,$templateSubject,$emailTemplateVariables){
         $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($loadtemplate);
            if($bccEmail){
                    $emailTemplate->addBcc($bccEmail);
            }
            $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($templateSubject);
            $sData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/email');
            $sData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/name');
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName($sData['name']);
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($sData['email']);
try{
            $emailTemplate->send($email,Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(),$emailTemplateVariables);
            }catch(exception $e){Mage::log($e,null,'system.log');}
    }
```

}
Getting exception:

```
        #0 /var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
        #1 /var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/Zend_Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
       #2 /var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.php(454): Zend_Mail->send()
        #3/var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/J2t_Smsgateway_Model_Emailtemplate.php(23): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('__________@gm...', 'Default Store V...', Array)
       #4/var/www/magento/magento/app/code/local/Seller/SellerDirectory/controllers/IndexController.php(182): J2t_Smsgateway_Model_Emailtemplate->send('__________@gm...', 'Default Store V...', Array)
 #5/var/www/magento/magento/app/code/local/Seller/SellerDirectory/controllers/IndexController.php(86): Seller_SellerDirectory_IndexController->commonmail('__________@gm...', 'false', 'seller_registra...', 'Seller Registra...', Array)
#6 /var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/__default.php(419): Seller_SellerDirectory_IndexController->responseAction()
#7 /var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/__default.php(18718): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('response')
#8 /var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/__default.php(18252): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 #9 /var/www/magento/magento/includes/src/__default.php(20852): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 #10 /var/www/magento/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 #11 /var/www/magento/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
 #12 {main}
```

Need help,stuck cannot debug...

Comment: Have you tried logging the sent mail and checking whether it has the right html template? Have you checked the headers.? If mail headers are not set as html it won't show up as it should in the recieved email.

Comment: i am using two template ,when use template1 then template is showing in mail ,if i use another template it is not...I have added code

Comment: have you defined email template in xml?

Comment: yes i have defined in config.xml

Comment: Is this issue by varnish..or something other...